# Why am I getting data from the database slowly?

Tags: node.js, database, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I use nestjs with typeorm and postgresql, I get data from the database in 150-200ms, but if you wait 20 seconds and send a request to the backend again and get the data, then I get the data in 1000ms or 1500ms, although in theory and in general it should usually be 150- 200ms? Tried to use sequelize result was same. As if, if you wait, the server starts to fall asleep and wakes up for a long time when the request goes to it again.
This is code how I do request to database:

```
async getProducts() {
   const products = await this.productRepository.find();
   return products;
}
```

Please any ideas, answers, options

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that Nestjs is adding a significant delay here. The code you posted looks okay-ish.

Try removing the "surroundings" (as in moving parts) to get to the bottom of this. E.g. execute this method in the main.ts

Hint: if your service would be called `MyService` you could access it there like this:

```
const service = app.get(MyService);
```

Another way would be to remove everything that is involved in the response of the request:

- Your code from controller -> service -> repository
- Code that could intercept: Middlewares, Pipes, Guards, Interceptors

By switching Sequelize to TypeORM you kinda removed the DB communication layer as a suspect, if your investigation does not yield anything helpful you should consider looking into the underlying DB and the specified connection options (if any, e.g. pool size). Most likely the causing code should be in the application tho. For Sequelize and TypeScript, you can also enable logging to get better insights. Good luck on your research!